# Test Suite is not running in Katalon Studio

Tags: web-services, groovy, katalon-studio, test-suite

I'm trying to execute test suite, but it is stuck at: Launching the test suite...

and when I click after 1 min it is not responding and closes.

[image]

Comment: Pls share your console log

Comment: test suite launches very slowly, it launches like after 1-2 min, now I have executed and when it will finish I will share my log. And when it finishes 1 test case it needs also 1 min to go on next test case

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/XoPUjyC , well it shows that it ran in 3 sec....

Comment: Pls share also your test skript and the relevant html code

Comment: it doesn't have html code, I'm making API requests and then I compare it with database datas.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/D2aWNYp this is my script in test case, in test suite I use data files also

Comment: What is your current version of Katalon? Does your test run under former Katalon versions?

Comment: my katalon version is 5.11.0

Comment: I think the problem is in my current project, because when I created new project with everything empty, it ran very fast. But why is in my current project test suite slow ?

Comment: Did you run this with any of the previous versions?

Comment: I was able to run this yesterday with current version, but from yesterday midnight, it is not working anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem.
I followed these steps:

1. Reinstall KS.
2. Remove lib, bin, class path, project from Project folder.
3. Start KS
4. Refresh KS, Project>Refresh.

Now it is working how it should be.